# How to use Java app to convert parquet dataset to delta

Tags: java, apache-spark, parquet, delta-lake

im trying to convert parquet file to delta using java , using java 11 and spark and scale as maven dependencies while trying to exceute im getting Exception

```java
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().
appName("Solo-spark").master("local[1]").getOrCreate();`
```

Here we have get a spark session.

Now you have covert to delta using

```java
DeltaTable
    .convertToDelta(spark,"parquet.`/Users/hokage/Downloads/python-paraquet`");
```

and im getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/$less$colon$less
    at org.soloworld.App.main(App.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.$less$colon$less
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 1 more
```

and these are my dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.delta</groupId>
      <artifactId>delta-core_2.13</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.delta</groupId>
      <artifactId>delta-iceberg_2.13</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please give it a try to see https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-standalone.html#maven

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up different Scala versions - you're using libraries compiled for Scala 2.13 (the `_2.13` suffix) with the Scala 2.12 (the `2.12.17`) version.  You also need to check for which Scala version the Apache Spark distribution is compiled.

P.S. You also don't need `delta-iceberg` dependency to convert from Parquet to Delta format.

Answer (score 0):

## Create Parquet Dataset

Yours was `/Users/hokage/Downloads/python-paraquet`, but let's use `/tmp/parquet-dataset` if you don't mind

Let's open `spark-shell` and write some Scala. This is only to create a parquet table (dataset).

```scala
val parquetTableDir = "/tmp/parquet-dataset"
```

```scala
spark
  .range(5)
  .write
  .format("parquet")
  .save(parquetTableDir)
```

```bash
$ ls -l /tmp/parquet-dataset
total 48
-rw-r--r--@ 1 jacek  wheel    0 May 17 09:32 _SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--@ 1 jacek  wheel  297 May 17 09:32 part-00000-f01e6a39-220a-401b-bfd0-2f9bd1712981-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--@ 1 jacek  wheel  472 May 17 09:32 part-00002-f01e6a39-220a-401b-bfd0-2f9bd1712981-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--@ 1 jacek  wheel  472 May 17 09:32 part-00004-f01e6a39-220a-401b-bfd0-2f9bd1712981-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--@ 1 jacek  wheel  471 May 17 09:32 part-00007-f01e6a39-220a-401b-bfd0-2f9bd1712981-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--@ 1 jacek  wheel  472 May 17 09:32 part-00009-f01e6a39-220a-401b-bfd0-2f9bd1712981-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--@ 1 jacek  wheel  472 May 17 09:32 part-00011-f01e6a39-220a-401b-bfd0-2f9bd1712981-c000.snappy.parquet
```

### Java Project (Maven)

I used IntelliJ IDEA to create a Java project with Maven. It's been a while since I've done it!

#### pom.xml

Mind all the dependencies and their versions. They have to match and important things are:

1. The version of Scala (Delta Lake and Apache Spark deps)
2. [Delta Lake 2.3.0 supports Spark 3.3](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/releases/tag/v2.3.0)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>delta-convert</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.delta</groupId>
            <artifactId>delta-core_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

### Java Application

```java
package so;

import io.delta.tables.DeltaTable;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class DeltaConvert {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("Solo-spark")
                .master("local[*]") // Use the star instead
                // the following configs are required for Delta Lake to run on Spark
                .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
                .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
                .getOrCreate();

        DeltaTable
                .convertToDelta(spark,"parquet.`/tmp/parquet-dataset`");

    }
}
```

### Show Time

Execute the Java app and you should see tons of INFO messages in the console (standard output). Among the lines you should find the following:

```
23/05/17 09:41:19 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.3.2
...
23/05/17 09:41:22 INFO DelegatingLogStore: LogStore `LogStoreAdapter(io.delta.storage.HDFSLogStore)` is used for scheme `file`
23/05/17 09:41:22 INFO DeltaLog: Creating initial snapshot without metadata, because the directory is empty
23/05/17 09:41:24 INFO InitialSnapshot: [tableId=b071541b-9864-4a06-a8d5-d45690ab1a26] Created snapshot InitialSnapshot(path=file:/tmp/parquet-dataset/_delta_log, version=-1, metadata=Metadata(2876805c-dde3-4d69-96a2-d2c3ad3c81e7,null,null,Format(parquet,Map()),null,List(),Map(),Some(1684309284165)), logSegment=LogSegment(file:/tmp/parquet-dataset/_delta_log,-1,List(),List(),None,-1), checksumOpt=None)
23/05/17 09:41:24 INFO DeltaLog: No delta log found for the Delta table at file:/tmp/parquet-dataset/_delta_log
23/05/17 09:41:24 INFO InitialSnapshot: [tableId=2876805c-dde3-4d69-96a2-d2c3ad3c81e7] Created snapshot InitialSnapshot(path=file:/tmp/parquet-dataset/_delta_log, version=-1, metadata=Metadata(29ac2dc9-a37b-47cd-9aec-45090056afcc,null,null,Format(parquet,Map()),null,List(),Map(),Some(1684309284204)), logSegment=LogSegment(file:/tmp/parquet-dataset/_delta_log,-1,List(),List(),None,-1), checksumOpt=None)
...
23/05/17 09:41:26 INFO DeltaFileOperations: Listing file:/tmp/parquet-dataset
23/05/17 09:41:26 INFO DelegatingLogStore: LogStore `LogStoreAdapter(io.delta.storage.HDFSLogStore)` is used for scheme `file`
...
23/05/17 09:41:41 INFO FileScanRDD: Reading File path: file:///tmp/parquet-dataset/_delta_log/00000000000000000000.checkpoint.parquet, range: 0-13899, partition values: [empty row]
...
23/05/17 09:41:41 INFO Snapshot: [tableId=11d76ddd-3035-47b5-9dfe-f7e14de9ef71] Created snapshot Snapshot(path=file:/tmp/parquet-dataset/_delta_log, version=0, metadata=Metadata(11d76ddd-3035-47b5-9dfe-f7e14de9ef71,null,null,Format(parquet,Map()),{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"id","type":"long","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]},List(),Map(),Some(1684309287681)), logSegment=LogSegment(file:/tmp/parquet-dataset/_delta_log,0,ArraySeq(),ArraySeq(DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus{path=file:/tmp/parquet-dataset/_delta_log/00000000000000000000.checkpoint.parquet; isDirectory=false; length=13899; replication=1; blocksize=33554432; modification_time=1684309298044; access_time=1684309297927; owner=; group=; permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false; hasAcl=false; isEncrypted=false; isErasureCoded=false}),Some(0),1684309291045), checksumOpt=None)
23/05/17 09:41:41 INFO DeltaLog: Updated snapshot to Snapshot(path=file:/tmp/parquet-dataset/_delta_log, version=0, metadata=Metadata(11d76ddd-3035-47b5-9dfe-f7e14de9ef71,null,null,Format(parquet,Map()),{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"id","type":"long","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]},List(),Map(),Some(1684309287681)), logSegment=LogSegment(file:/tmp/parquet-dataset/_delta_log,0,ArraySeq(),ArraySeq(DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus{path=file:/tmp/parquet-dataset/_delta_log/00000000000000000000.checkpoint.parquet; isDirectory=false; length=13899; replication=1; blocksize=33554432; modification_time=1684309298044; access_time=1684309297927; owner=; group=; permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false; hasAcl=false; isEncrypted=false; isErasureCoded=false}),Some(0),1684309291045), checksumOpt=None)
...
```

#### PySpark

Use `pyspark` (with Delta Lake "installed") to access the delta table.

```bash
$ ./bin/pyspark \
  --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.3.0 \
  --conf spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension \
  --conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.3.2
      /_/

Using Python version 3.10.11 (main, May 10 2023 19:07:22)
Spark context Web UI available at http://192.168.68.101:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1684309786375).
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
```

```
>>> spark.read.format("delta").load("/tmp/parquet-dataset").show(truncate = False)
+---+
|id |
+---+
|0  |
|3  |
|4  |
|1  |
|2  |
+---+
```